# How are "feature_importances_" ordered in Scikit-learn's RandomForestRegressor

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

If I run a model (called clf in this case), I get output that looks like this.  How can I tie this to the feature inputs that were used to train the classifier?

```
>>> clf.feature_importances_

array([ 0.01621506,  0.18275428,  0.09963659,... ])
```

Comment: The order is the order of the features in your feature vectors.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it looks like the order or feature importances is the order of the "x" input variable (which I've converted from Pandas to a Python native data structure). I use this code to generate a list of types that look like this: (feature_name, feature_importance).

```
zip(x.columns, clf.feature_importances_)
```

Comment: As larsmans says, the obvious answer is the right one. Glad I got some confirmation, thanks!

Comment: Would you say what is `x` and what is `x.columns`?

Comment: What @Bach says and technically your answer is not answering your question, it is just code that generates tuples :) Moreover you seem to be using `pandas.DataFrame`s which actually don't work with `sklearn` (at the moment, unclear for the future afaik).

Comment: Ok @eickenberg good points.  I added some clarification to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You may save the result in a pandas data frame as follows:

```
pandas.DataFrame({'col_name': clf.feature_importances_}, index=x.columns).sort_values(by='col_name', ascending=False)
```

By sorting it in a descending manner we get a hint to significant features.

Answer (score 0):

The order is  the order of the features/attributes of your training/data set.

You can display these importance scores next to their corresponding attribute/features names as below:

```
attributes = list(your_data_set)

sorted(zip(clf.feature_importances_, attributes), reverse=True)
```

The output could be something similar:

```
[(0.01621506, 'feature1'),
(0.09963659, 'feature2'),
(0.18275428, 'feature3'),
...
...
```