# XGBoost feature importance in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, xgboost

I would like to ask if there is a way to pull the names of the most important features and save them in pandas data frame. I know how to plot them and how to get them, but I'm looking for a way to save the most important features in a data frame.

```py
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from xgboost import plot_importance

# fit model to training data
xgb_model = XGBClassifier(random_state=0)
xgb_model.fit(X, y)

print("Feature Importances : ", xgb_model.feature_importances_)

# plot feature importance
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 10))
plot_importance(xgb_model, max_num_features=35, height=1, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get actual feature names in XGBoost feature importance plot without retraining the model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54933804/how-to-get-actual-feature-names-in-xgboost-feature-importance-plot-without-retra)

Answer (score 0):

To show the most important features used by the model you can use and then save them into a dataframe.

```
xgb.plot_importance({model})
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [6, 4]
plt.show()
```

Comment: How to save it? you showed how to plot it only

Answer (score 0):

```
pandas.DataFrame({'col_name': clf.feature_importances_}, index=x.columns).sort_values(by='col_name', ascending=False)
```

This saves your features into a dataframe.
From: [How are "feature_importances_" ordered in Scikit-learn's RandomForestRegressor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23900080/how-are-feature-importances-ordered-in-scikit-learns-randomforestregressor)
By: Abishek Parida